# Reauthentication Code in App Delegate?

Tags: ios, authentication, networking, appdelegate

So basically I am using Cookie authentication. The cookie expires after 1 HR. I am trying to cover an edge use case that if the user has the app in active foreground for more than 1 HR straight, how to  refresh the cookie. Basically, I need to make a login call with my token in the background to reauthenticate and refresh the cookie before any of the network calls work again.

Should I be putting this reauthentication code inside the App Delegate since I have multiple view controllers that do network calls? Is this a good practice or should I be putting the code in the root view controller?

My idea is basically to look for 401 error code and do a NSNotification to the App Delegate to reauthenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timestamp (for example in `NSUserDefaults`) when application resigns active (`applicationWillResignActive:`), and calculate time difference when the app is active again (`applicationDidBecomeActive:`). If the time difference is greater than some amount (say an hour) you should reauthenticate the app and get a new cookie.

Also 401 depended notification method would be useful, because server may return 401 for other reasons.